# How to generate simulation output report when using SimPy 3

Tags: python, simpy

How to generate simulation reports with SimPy 3? I was reading [here](https://pythonhosted.org/SimPy/Manuals/Manual.html) that for the version 2 it's possible to do something like this:

```
simulate(until=1000.0)

Report()  #  report results when the simulation finishes
```

However I cannot find the reporting function for SimPy 3. The report should include, for instance, average throughtput of a server, resource utilization, and other statistics.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For performance reason, SimPy 3 no longer monitors your simulation by default.  There is [this guide](https://simpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/topical_guides/monitoring.html) that discusses ways to monitor your simulation and collect data.

Comment: Ok, so it means that if I want to calculate, for instance, the average queue length, I should patch the Resource class as described in the link, and store all the <time, queue_length> pairs in the list. Then, after the simulation is finished, I should calculate the average queue length myself using the formula, sum(Ti*QLi)/total_time. This is the approach, right?

Comment: Yes, for example. :)